# Equivalence of Parameterizations of Least Squares Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Give problem data $(A, b)$ where $A$ is an $n \times m$ full-rank matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, one may pose the least squares problem as unconstrained optimization

$\text{argmin}_x\, || Ax -b ||^2$

There is an alternate formulation as a constrained optimization. Given problem data $(\hat A, \hat b)$ where $\hat A$ is an $\hat n \times \hat m$ matrix and $\hat b \in \mathbb {R} ^ m$

$\text {argmin}_z || z ||^2\,\,\,\, \text {such that} \,\hat A z = \hat b$

I want to show that both formulations are equivalent, in that there is a bijection between problems $(A,b,x) \cong (z,\hat A, \hat b)$.

By "bijection", I mean that, given computer algorithms $\text{solve}_1(A,b)$ which optimizes problems of the first type, and $\text{solve}_2(\hat A, \hat b)$ which optimizes problems of the second type, there exists conversion algorithms $f$ and $g$ such that $\text{solve}_1(f(\hat A, \hat b)) = \text{solve}_2(\hat A, \hat b)$ and  $\text{solve}_1(A, b) = \text{solve}_2(g( A, b))$

It seems clear by geometrical argument - both formulations are minimizing the distance of an affine set to some particular point. But is there an easy expression / algorithm that computes the transformation?

I guess the main complication here is that $Ax - b$ is a parameterization using the image, while $\hat A z = \hat b$ is a parameterization using the kernel.

Comment: What are $\hat A$ and $\hat b$?

Comment: They are any matrix and any vector with compatible dimensions. What I tried to do is tersely describe a space of problems. I'll try to clarify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is somewhat imprecise, I just formulate a thought. Consider the problems
$$
\min_x\|Ax-b\|^2
$$
and
$$
\min_z\|z\|^2 \quad\text{s.t. $A^Tz = A^Tb$}.
$$
The relation $A^Tz = A^Tb$ means $z-b\in\ker(A^T)$ or $z\in b + \ker(A^T)$. We have $\Bbb R^m = \ker(A^T)\oplus ran(A)$. Hence, we can write $b = b_1+b_2$ with $b_1\in\ker(A^T)$ and $b_2\in ran(A)$. Then $z\in b+\ker(A^T)$ means $z\in b_2+\ker(A^T)$, so $z = b_2 + u$ with $u\in\ker(A^T)$. Hence, $\|z\|^2 = \|b_2\|^2 + \|u\|^2$. The minimum is of course when $u=0$, i.e., $z =  b_2$, which is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $ran A$. That is, $z = Ax_0$ and $\|Ax_0-b\|^2\le\|Ax-b\|^2$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$. Hence, $\|z-b\|^2$ is the solution to the first problem.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question a little bit. I hope it is more clear now. What is $x_0$?

Comment: $b_2\in ran(A)$, so there exists $x_0$  such that $b_2 = Ax_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume $m \le n$.

The set $\{Ax - b : x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ is an affine space and can be described as the image of $A$ translated by $-b$.

The image of $A$ is a subspace, and is the kernel of some matrix $\hat{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-m) \times n}$.

Then,
$$\{Ax - b : x \in \mathbb{R}^m\} = -b + \text{Image}(A) = -b + \text{Ker}(\hat{A}) =  \{z : \hat{A} z = -\hat{A}b\}.$$

---

The correspondence is not bijective. For a given $A$, any full rank matrix $\hat{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-m) \times n}$ satisfying $\hat{A}^\top A = 0$ will work.

Comment: I think the matrix dimensions are not compatible in the expression $\hat A^T A$